# What type is q in "void foo(int q[][4]){}" ?How is using "void foo(int q[6][4]){}" different from the former?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am certain `q` in `int q[6][4]` is of type `(**q)[4]`, ie, `pointer to a pointer to an integer array sized 4`. But the book I have (I find it dubious!!) says that the `int q[][4]` part in the function definition `void foo(int q[][4]){}` is the same as `int (*q)[4]`.I am ambivalent about the book, yet let me present for your  consideration some issues that crop up in my mind over this.Your detailed explanation is very much sought.

**1)**  During declaration,is  the type of `q` in `int q[][4]` the same as in `int q[6][4]`? Contrary to what the book says, I see `q[][4]` as nothing but `q[0][4]` and I feel q is of type `(**q)[4]`,and not `(*q)[4]`.Am I right?What's your take on it?

**2)**  **(Most confusing bit)** I know passing `int *q` and `int q[]` (or `int q[4]`) is the same in C as the latter reduces to the former.But I have verified from the compiler that `int (*q)[5]` is not the same type as `int (*q)[4]`, so what is the difference between passing as arguments to a function **A)** `int (*q)[]` **B)**`int (*q)[4]` and **C)**`int (*q)[5]` ? Please be detailed for the answer to this part.

**3)** How is passing `int q[][4]` to a function different from passing `int q[6][4]` in C?Does `q` reduce to `(**q)[4]` in both cases?

Comment: @hyde "In C, "array of integers" is basically same thing as "pointer to integer"" - ***Please, for the love of God, DO NOT TELL THIS WRONG EXPLANATION to beginners!!!*** Thanks.

Comment: @H2CO3 Please refute that remark of hyde with a rigorous technical explanation, even if it's concise.I really need that.Hyde is indeed both confusing and convincing !!

Comment: @SheerFish I just did that in my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 My question sounds messy and confusing indeed.Hence it has been voted down.But the issue itself is confusing and messy and I didn't have better words to put my point across.Glad that I got good answers

Comment: @H2CO3 I misread the types a bit for that deleted comment so it was overall bad, but "*in C, array of integers decays to a pointer to integer*" is pretty much a more formal way of saying "*in C, array of integers is basically same thing as pointer to integer, with a few subtle differences*". Before that is understood, IME it's very hard to understand what some actual piece of array/pointer code *does*, and what the array/pointer differences are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am certain q in `int q[6][4]` is of type `(**q)[4]`, ie, pointer to a pointer to an integer array sized 4

No. (The pointer-to-pointer-to-array is very, very far from the truth, specifically.) `q` is of type `int[6][4]`, i. e. an array of 6 arrays of 4 integers.

When passed to a function, it's **only the first (innermost) dimension of an array that decays into a pointer.** So, `int[6][4]` decays into `int (*)[4]`, and so does `int[][4]`.

> `int (*q)[5]` is not the same type as `int (*q)[4]`, so what is the difference between passing as arguments to a function A) `int (*q)[]` B) `int (*q)[4]` and C) `int (*q)[5]`

A) is an incomplete type (pointer to array of any size). You can't dereference it, nor can you perform pointer arithmetic on it.

B) is a pointer to array of 4 `int`s. C) is a pointer to array of 5 `int`s.

> How is passing `int q[][4]` to a function different from passing `int q[6][4]` in C?

Semantically, they mean the same. They both decay into `int (*)[4]`.

> Does q reduce to `(**q)[4]` in both cases?

No, but I've already explained that.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, `q` is an array of array of four integers.

You might want to read about the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). It might actually help you with the second question.

Comment: Please add some details to your answer as you generally do.A lot of guys like me must be having the same confusion that I have tried to mention in this question

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that one needs to be careful using that rule when dealing with multi-dimensional arrays: `int *a[2][3]` is clearly not an array of pointers to an array of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) During declaration,is the type of q in int q[][4] the same as in
>   int q[6][4]?

Yes. The first dimension is not needed in a function declaration and a multidimensional array **in a function declaration** has type `pointer to an array`.

> what is the difference between passing as arguments to a function A)
>   int (*q)[] B)int (*q)[4] and C)int (*q)[5] ?

`int (*q)[]` is a pointer to an array of unknown size. `int (*q)[4]` is a pointer to `int[4]` and `int (*q)[5]` is a pointer to `int[5]`. They all have different types.

> 3) How is passing int q[][4] to a function different from passing int
>   q[6][4] in C?Does q reduce to (**q)[4] in both cases?

They are both equivalent to `int (*q)[4]`.

Pleas read [23.1: Multidimensional Arrays and Functions](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html) of the c.faq for more details.

Comment: How come `q` in `int q[6][4]`  pointer to an array? Here `q[6]` is certainly an array of pointers and hence `q` is of type `pointer to pointer`.What's wrong with my argument?

Comment: @SheerFish No, `q` isn't an array of pointers, it's an array of arrays (an array of 6 arrays of 4 `int`s), and it decays into a pointer to array of 4 `int`s.

Comment: @H2CO3 I meant to say the `q[6]` part is an array of pointers as it stores the base address of arrays of size 4.And `q` being the base address of such an array of pointers, is hence of type `int (**q)[4]`.Aint' I right?

Comment: @SheerFish No, the `q[6]` part is an array of 6 arrays of 4 `int`s. **It is not** an array of pointers. It doesn't hold the base addresses of the arrays of 4 `int`s, it holds those **arrays themselves.** Arrays, even multidimensional ones, are contiguous in memory.

Comment: @SheerFish: In `q[6]`, you get a pointer to the **first element**. Not a pointer to an array.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is this statement of Jesse correct `"multidimensional array has type pointer to an array."`?

Comment: @SheerFish No, since arrays aren't pointers. A multidimensional array is of type "array of arrays".

Comment: @SheerFish It's not entirely accurate. Currently he claims that arrays **are** pointers, whereas the truth is that arrays **decay into** pointers **when passed as a function argument.**

Comment: @H2CO3: No, I'm talking about the syntax in a function parameter.

Comment: @H2CO3 So what would be the correct and rigorous version of Jesse's statement?You tell that so that I can note it!!

Comment: @SheerFish I've already repeated that at least 3 times, last time in my previous comment.

Comment: @H2CO3 So shall I conclude `Jesse Good` is `Jesse Bad`?

Comment: @H2CO3 or `Jesse not entirely bad`?`Jesse not entirely good`?

Comment: @SheerFish Good, because he edited his answer in order to be correct :P

Comment: @SheerFish: It seems my answer didn't help, so I will delete this in a little bit. Please read [all the c.faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) under `Arrays and Pointers` and see if that clears up things.

Comment: @JesseGood DONT delete your answer.It helped as H2CO3 clarified a lot of things through it

Comment: @JesseGood I have a habit of teasing people's names playfully.So don't mind.All right `Jesse Bad`?

Comment: @JesseGood Here, +1 to acknowledge that it really helped.

Comment: Jesse's answer to question 1 is correct considering the context of the title of the question, which specifically asks about `int q[][4]` vs. `int q[6][4]` as parameters. And the answer is that they are both actually `int (*q)[4]` according to the C standard. It would be different if someone were to ask about them as global variable declarations or something.